# Trial 0 failed, because the value <function mean_squared_error at 0x000001799EEFB5E0> could not be cast to float

Tags: machine-learning, catboost

I am trying to tune catboost classifier with Optuna.

I am getting this message to all my trials:

```
[W 2022-10-05 15:05:30,474] Trial 0 failed, because the value <function mean_squared_error at 0x000001799EEFB5E0> could not be cast to float.
```

Below is my code. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
def objective(trial):
    """Define the objective function"""

    params = {
        'depth': trial.suggest_int('depth', 1, 16),
        'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.001, 1.0),
        'iterations': trial.suggest_int('iterations', 1, 1750),
        'verbose':True,
       
    }
    
 # Fit the model
    optuna_model = CatBoostRegressor(**params)
    optuna_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Make predictions
    y_pred = optuna_model.predict(X_val)

    # Evaluate predictions
    accuracy = mean_squared_error(y_val, y_pred)
    return mean_squared_error   


study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize')
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=6)


print('Number of finished trials: {}'.format(len(study.trials)))
print('Best trial:')
trial = study.best_trial

print('  Value: {}'.format(trial.value))
print('  Params: ')

for key, value in trial.params.items():
    print('    {}: {}'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: This is wrong: return mean_squared_error

Answer (score 0):

You caculate the MSE and then assign to `accuracy`, but return a variable `mean_squared error` that is undefined. Thus replace:

```py
# Evaluate predictions
accuracy = mean_squared_error(y_val, y_pred)
return mean_squared_error
```

with:

```py
return mean_squared_error(y_val, y_pred)
```

Also, you are also optimizing in the wrong direction. As noted in the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html), MSE is best, if equal or close to zero. Thus, set the direction to:

```
study = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize')
```